# MariaDb: Mejorar performance de queries con LIKE

Tags: mariadb, rendimiento

Para mi proyecto necesito hacer consultas con [LIKE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/like/). Leyendo la parte de *[optimazing like](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/like/#optimizing-like)* solamente menciona que se debe hacer uso de *[optimizer_use_condition_selectivity](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#optimizer_use_condition_selectivity)*, sin embargo, no me es demasiado clara la documentación. No entiendo qué se debe hacer o cómo se debe aplicar esa optimización; hasta el momento me parece un *flag* ¿Pero de qué?

Además leyendo [este otro artículo](https://www.fabriciolima.net/blog/2017/02/08/improve-the-query-performance-with-like-string-changing-only-the-collation/) (Pero de SQL no MariaDb) recomiendan crear un un índice de esta forma.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SK01_Test_Collation_SQL ON table_name (column_name) WITH(FILLFACTOR=90)
```

¿Debería procurar uno para mi tabla también o con lo de arriba sería suficiente?, ¿Cómo sería para MaríaDb en ese caso?

Como información adicional así se ve mi tabla (quité todas las llaves foráneas) y la consulta será sobre la columna ***title***.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Thesis_Detail;
CREATE TABLE Thesis_Detail(
    thesis_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    file VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    abstract TEXT NOT NULL,
    uploaded_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    INDEX(title)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que hallé y se me había olvidado publicar es que hacer un índice para la búsqueda de texto sólo funciona para *queries* del estilo `LIKE 'Texto%'`, lo cual no es útil para el proprósito de hacer una búsqueda completa (`'%Texto%'`).

Por lo cual es mejor hacer uso de [FULLTEXT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-text-index-overview/), el cual te permite hacer búsqueda por porciones.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Thesis_Detail(
    thesis_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    file VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    abstract TEXT NOT NULL,
    uploaded_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FULLTEXT(title)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Así quedaría entonces la tabla y una consulta se vería como:

```
SELECT * WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```